# How long does it take for a snail to mature into an adult?

Tags: snails, saltwater

I recently bought some turbo snails.  Shortly after, I was gifted with a ton of little snails that come out after dark.  Unfortunately, they seem to just be food for everyone else.  Maybe I should try to put them in the sump?

How fast should the snails grow / how long until they reach their full size?

Comment: If, by "sump", you mean somewhere outside of your house, then ABSOLUTELY NOT.  Snails can be an invasive species and destroy ecosystems; this is happening already with large snails and certain parts of Florida.  Never release a pet you can't keep into the wild.  Bring them to the pet store to get rid of them, or continue to let them become food.

Comment: No, an aquarium sump is a separate tank for your display to drain into (where you can hide heaters and other equipment) and then returned.  It also serves as a separate habitat for macro algae and sometimes incompatible fish.  I definitely want to keep them; their becoming food is the opposite of what I want to happen.  Haha, I don't think saltwater snails would invade too efficiently.

Comment: Got it.  In the neighborhood where I grew up, the "sump" was a wet, depressed, woodsy area where all the rainwater from houses drained to; combined with my lack of aquarium knowledge, you can understand my confusion on the term.

Comment: Yeah, it's one of those terms you start throwing around loosely in the hobby and it's pretty confusing from the outside looking in.

Comment: @snailboat - If you're still hanging about, this is right up your alley. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Growth rate and how large they get depends on they environment and the genus. Many can grow to about 1" in six months or so, then continue growing from there. It is common for a lot of the baby snails to not last the long.

Comment: Hopefully I can keep my lion fish full enough to not be tempted by the midnight snack until then.  Thanks for the input.